# Display several graphics from different sheets in one sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cRIUX5lwJVkr_INcXj_rawndSzGlVHalliaIfEZXZzI/edit#gid=1511798751

In the `Search` sheet I have a scrolling menu where I can sort my refs by months...

When a month is selected it display a graphic from the data in `grade` column...

Is it possible to display all the graphics in one single sheet to compare then at the first sight? For now I have data only for January, February and March...

Also, is it possible to use the month name as a title for each graph ?

I think I need a function that find the expected sheet, the required month and the plage...

`=Grades!C:C`
but I am just stuck here...

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, by the term "Graphics" do you mean you want a Graph that contains all of your date for all months in a single sheet?

Comment: Just on per month (all in on sheet)

Answer (score 2):

to get array you can use one of these approaches:

```
={Grades!C1:C300}

=INDEX(Grades!C1:C300)

=QUERY(Grades!C1:C300)

=ARRAYFORMULA(Grades!C1:C300)
```